# How to get Redirect() to work how I want

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been having some problems getting redirects after login to work how I want. So I came up with the idea to store the current page in the viewbag and use that to redirect, so if the page is mydomain.com/debate/1 I end up with  "/debate/1" stored in the viewbad but when I try to redirect its giving me this complaint

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DebateDetails(Int32)' in 'PoliticalDebate.Controllers.DebateController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

However If I manually type in mydomain.com/Debate/1 it works as expected.

Is there some way to get Redirect to work how I want ?

Comment: Thanks to all, the discussion forced me to find the problem

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't see any code, I can't comment on the way you are trying to do it (which isn't working).  On future posts, *please post your code*.  This is one way how you can redirect if you are simply redirecting to the default action on the controller:

```
return this.RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = debateDetailsID } );
```

Although it's very hard to tell what you are truly trying to do because you mention `debate/1` yet the method being called is `DebateDetails` which doesn't match (unless you've changed the default routes, again I don't know, there's no code).

**Update**

According to your comment, you have an error in your MapRoute.  Your MapRoute should look like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Debate Details", 
                "debate/{id}", 
                 new { controller = "Debate", 
                       action = "DebateDetails",
                       // this id value is missing 
                       // so it's not being passed to the controller
                       id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Comment: Im getting this value on every page Request.Url.AbsolutePath and storing it in the viewbag. The idea is whenever I hit LogOn I can use the current value in ViewBag to redirect the user properly. I can't rely on The built in ASP membership bits to redirect properly everytime because of my use of ajax and openid integration.

Comment: I don't believe I can comment further without seeing your redirect code.

Comment: The redirect code is simply Redirect(ViewBag.Page) ViewBag.Page contains the value from Request.Url.AbsolutePath

Comment: Can you explain why your URL is `debate/1` and your error message is for the method `DebateDetails`?

Comment: Custom route  routes.MapRoute(
                "Debate Details",
                "debate/{id}",
                new { controller = "Debate", action = "DebateDetails" }
                );

Comment: actually thats the problem them hahaha when I type debate/test to test the redirct its trying to go to Debate/Details and pull test

Answer (score 0):

the answer is there in the complaint, in this particular case you're sending a parameter so, checkout if this is specified

your code must look like `redirectToAction("nameOfAction", new {id = yourIdOnViewBag}`

Comment: Wont work, Its not always going to be an action with an ID it will be different URLS, I probably am setting it up in a non optimal way. My bad for being a newb